# X64 assembly: terminated by signal SIGBUS (Misaligned address error)

Tags: c, x86, 64-bit

I am writing a simple x64 program which calls a C program to print a string. I am using Mac OS X

X64:

```
.data

hello_world: .asciz "hello world!\n"

.globl _print_string
.globl _main

_main:

    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    leaq hello_world(%rip), %rdi
    callq _print_string

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
```

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void 
print_string(char *str) 
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

But why am i getting **'./output' terminated by signal SIGBUS (Misaligned address error)**. Can anyone please explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your `.s` file switches to the data segment, and never switches back. This leaves the `main` function in the data segment, which is not executable.

Switch back to the text segment using `.text` before you start writing any code. (Or switch to the data segment and define your string constant after `main`.)